# How can I remove these dots?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

When I zoom in and zoom out on my results. I see a lot of dots on my paper towel. How can I remove them?

[image: der]

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the preview to render more samples. As you can see in the information printed at the top it's at path tracing sample 1 out of 32.